# LBPH recognizer in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, opencv, face-recognition, lbph-algorithm

Is there any npm module present to implement Face Recognition in JavaScript? I am trying to mimic the LBPH classification that is mentioned in OpenCV using Python. Any work around to do the same in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV, or Open Source Computer Vision Library, is a powerful library used for image processing and image recognition. The library has a massive community and has been used extensively in many fields, from face detection to interactive art. It was first built in C++, but bindings have been created for different languages, such as Python and Java. It is even available in JavaScript as OpenCV.js, which is what we’ll be using for this tutorial.
(https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/computer-vision-js-frameworks-you-need-to-know-b233996103ce/)

. i don't know much, but Here is something which i find on internet
you can check this out if you  have any other issue please  ask more question on posts

Comment: I have already searched the internet and probably visited this link as well, but these libraries can only be used for object detection, though I wonder if we can create our own custom model using tensorflow.js. But still a little skeptical.